# How to get around IE8 32k limit on data:uri on base64 encode?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, png, content-type

I need to send an html response to the browser containing a 1920x1080 png. It's a screenshot taken by an html query.

I encode the image in base64 and sends it embedded as an text/html content-type. Something simple like :

```
<HTML><HEAD>Whatever</HEAD><BODY><img src="data:image/png;base64,data"/></BODY></HTML>
```

It works fine on FF and Chrome, the problem is I need to support IE8. IE8 as a limit on the length of the data:uri.

If I compress the image so the png encoding is under 32k (about 600x500) I lose too much information.

What would be the easiest work around for this problem? (I don't have access to a server to host the image or such)

Comment: Any specific reason why you want to send a 1920x1080 image via `src="data:`?

Comment: What would be my other options?

Comment: You do not need to support IE7 and IE6? Lucky Guy.

Comment: [This link](http://danielmclaren.com/node/90) seems to have a relevant solution, however, you will either need access to a server, or a client-side javascript module with routing that can fake a server response. Haven't tried it myself though.

Answer (score 18):

In the end we dropped IE8 support.

I'm lucky it's for internal debugging purpose only.

The problem still stand though. Hopefully IE9 won't have data:uri limit.

Comment: My favorite solution of all

Comment: i can't stop laughing at this =)))))))))))

Answer (score 4):

You could always break apart the image into 4 (or more) and encode each section separately.

Comment: can you please provide a link to example to, how to do that?

Comment: Yes @cobbal, can you post an example on how to do it?

Comment: I assume cobbal meant that you can display 4 images next to each other which, like a mosaic, will appear as one big image. This can be done by splitting the source image into 4 using any image editor, encoding each part separately, then placing them separately in the HTML using CSS to position them correctly.

Comment: You could split your base64 encoded string into smaller chunks. And reassemble the chunks into a string on the other end and display a single image. No need to render multiple images and align them.

Comment: @gfullam No, because the *resulting base64 encoded string* must be < 32k, not the *original image's disk size*.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just store the image somewhere, return its path, and then change src to the path you just generated?

Comment: No, I cannot store the image elsewhere or make its path available for outside request.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 encoded data URI is working fine in IE whose version is greater than or equal to 9. Since there is no data URI limitation for IE 9. Also I tried to fix this IE 8 issue. But I couldn't able to fix this issue. For Work around,storing images in somewhere inside your application & retrieve it back from application whenever displaying it.

In Rails views: (supports if IE >=9)

```
<b><%= ('&lt;img src="data:image/jpg;base64,%s">' % Base64.encode64(@chart.to_blob)).html_safe %></b>
```

In Rails views: (Supports all browsers)

```
<b><%= image_tag @chart+".png" %></b>
```