# what does this mean ? image/png;base64?

Tags: image, base64, data-uri

I don't know what we call this. but i found a image at google 404

```
url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKsAAADVCAMAAAAfHvCaAAAAGFBMVEVYn%2BH%2F%2F%2F%2Bex%2B3U5vd7s%2Bfq8%2Fs0itq72PMLUPvtAAASvklEQVR4AbXBC0JqCQxEwT5Jd7L%2FHc8FdR4g%2BEGtEr8u%2FBHxu7otdzd%2FQPyqlmRp1Pw%2B8aukDfRa1fw28ZtWy4sa89vEb7LCi0zx28RvqgkvouW3id%2FU8pbtWmv5beJXRWNrRmp%2BnfhlHXZm%2BQPi95Vk%2FoD4fZbMHxC%2FryTzB8Tva435A%2BL3rcb8AfH7VjJ%2FQPy%2BHYk%2FIH5facwfEL8iaZcrnKyn%2BAPi57K2VL2WF1hJ%2FAHxQ2tJrg6HteXVjPkD4ge6V3J1%2BF97zhx%2BnXhWb8nacKXlnYPErxNPyfqw4ZYKVuUZdfhd4hmxunY73NICgfWMOvwm8ZQ1pMvlDZdaCic98kjV4beIp8ScpLvsSvhflzqQmqVLB281v0E8pc2bdNne8EayNTPNSbt02PBj4intcKltb%2FNibY%2BLf9aSO%2FyMeMo6XMva3g0vwrWsxvyMeEoc3knZ2g53ZaXa8DzxlHa4J23Jae5aycXTxFPa4WRdXAtdsivckZXG4TniKWtOSlre6y7LG651Wxq5OzxDPGUVIKNwX6ekCv%2B0ddglVPMM8ZQ10FJ4LGVvOEuXRl7OqnmGeEor4Ck%2BtnI1ZEvjDa%2FcPEM8ZQVY4RO9VqUlN%2F84PEM8JQ50cUgXH2mrKlyq5RniOQ4vVjPLHdu86OKGi2eIr%2BgNV6JwljmYO6zlbJsbWp4hPtVrjYpLLV7UHIp7rOVkixtaniE%2BU5I2Nc2FKJytZhTuiac5rLnh4hniEzUbDjXhn3g5W0nNA1aAKm7YPEN8bMecrZYLWl70hkcyBay5YfMM8aHI4aR7xAUVHyirOdhAmRsqniE%2BtOKsRjIXtDzmmRGHVmDFDRfPEB%2BJzMmO01xScdYnVRs6vPHMFG9W4ZrMM8RHouWw43DNhlDWiSVZY3nDoWYc3qzDNZlniPe6w4uoOFjcKhPXuJNWyG6VqjSuhm7%2BiZorUfEM8U5J8nKyMw0tcZLwPxdRtTlUcUgVdGlml0uZ4pqKZ4hr5VUnpSXdUgVa4hA5vHERV1Tp9XhdJTWHksYd%2Ftdarql4hrjQiaPiYLclNSeebVYz5o0W7Ghsa9blmlFtx01rxP8yy5XIPEP8L1W7bjWHlbzhRTwjzXrCK1f3qqSEyBysLVtayKp40yqurcITxJtUgavVHNob%2FinZTWt5VVvWVKvJSttQCkRjb%2FA4vLK5thOeIN6sm9ai5cTFhYRDy%2FyTGpdU0hxkaZvWUrZluTmLims14QniVbywClqgeouT9IZXNWoupGzNqHa3y5LGVYBnipbCSVxcq1meIN54oRXsbEk26S3NmBcZ807K3gon2ZLcxF5tPMVJprlWE54g3nihtbRHm7WjkbxTHSCWwj1r2U4HSMmdQEmWwonNtah4gnhjA9ZSaohmpnpDjWRptDwS25LcQGsc2Bla5sTFtZV4gnixpWmIVWpgRuVwsiV5q7kv0JJcNVIFapydUrHTQKa5IfMEcRKrurSQ0qhsmVR4kea%2B7pIr9NqSrRltWlaxomUgVVyLxBPEYeUGygtszew2KfOBclVpVN2ctCXNidZaaKWmONhc6rKaJwi6xuGkRmWpAkRa7outF9XN%2F7LlmbJmpiCyvBxk%2FtnSqHmGWGk5i2ZcaWBLau5KKHt3Ce%2FsaLMz46VG4cTFm%2FaMOzxFUYWztjzhkNI43JPyYvPAegPxzFRpOYmWF1WywrPUag5xjRapqqxxubijvYFVaC%2Fv7YSDpzxjzlbhpKXxhqcpWshqtECk0Yys6m5utZdD1LCuCifhfyVOapqsxhyiQMmSm58QNdZheZGV5FqwueXiZBUga28DvRte1NQCpQVSUkFqPbIr%2FIxg7arwJqqEg6e5Vuas1Zytyw1ka5uT9ajKI87WbksaLT8mbkXFyWqaa2rOVuFVStUNpGrDoSTPmDfWdlby8kPiHQtoa0vLpXU4WzX%2FS5W2gWxtOHQ24U3CSUmu8BPinR2XVSFyuNAOZ9Fyae1qDu2qcF8suRKeJt7pcW1zaE9xwcVZq7nWtpeTrQ0PrEeq8CTxnsWrlbThELra5ixqbsXWNoeq6nBft6TlOeK9VnG2lfb4TKOOlpOouKPsWg4pb3Nf1uMGusP3iDtKDaTcgMuWvL1FmZOouCtlbwJs1Yb7SuN2Nd8k7mgvXV4OKWALiGkVJ14eyPqQQG9Vc0dWGnn5LnFPTW1z1gW0OdSyag5aHsvaroVs1YZL2dKMt1nzXeKulas52QLanGy3xq4a87Eu2yHZ2uZNWzPjDbDmu8R9a8m7iQNscbKyy%2BWS%2BUzWtqp7qzpA1jPj8KKK7xIPZG2NVWTTSbpKbs5cfEF6y64qV6ctqcKbdvgm8VhSlnWwJbuaV3LzRb11onFt%2BKcVvkl8one7u3bD%2FzJuXnRt%2BFTXVHOWqubQ4rvEEyI1L1Z2h8%2B0eRHLKiBqvkk8IePmxZq1lk%2B0w0nJUHKIlm8ST8ioeVEFtFwbPhA3h8gcdpZV803iCRkVL7Y42bK2w0NlDqXlpJRV803iGZYrnFRxlqwO3eEuN4dSOGlVme8Sz7C37QZqeZPekl0b3nMBreKsp1bNN4lnWIEtF1Vc6i1bVZtwxQX0NC9UrfBN4hk7zaHLNrey1kgVLljATnO2rmj5JvEMqzlrF%2B%2BFXitcsAArnFkdLd8knrFqPmFzyQq0xUm0tJZvEs8oAR0eix0u1ARSqg70NNHyTeIZUqgZ85gdLlgcMjOSRlBqvkk8wwOSp3moJlyoCYfeKkmBVvgm8YyaUJJ5zOJSTXMWSgus%2BC7xjJpA%2BMiquVATXiUcSuGbxDNqmk%2BUxtW82WmurMI3iWd4wifaHo1rNxx2miul8E3iGTXhc4nH0lQ1O80VK3yTeEYNX5SspbEnXFmFbxLPqGm%2BrsvWFFdK4ZvEM2rCt6RmzCWL7xLP2Anfs2M3Fyy%2BSzyjpvmqDoed5YrFd4ln7DRftHI19BRXSuGbxDN6wtdEqjF4lisS3yWeEYUvWlkDNeZKTfgm8ZFu7mqFr%2FKMYae4lFH4JvGBVLgraghf09uQMZdabr5JfKC2q1zV3IgarOLLPMWllptvEo%2B1e7dkq5ZrLkip%2BKqa4lLk5ZvEY15INay9XIqXVGS%2BqsdcirzclYVa7hAPbQFVnJSaC9HCapavqjGXIjXvbNmSxi7eE4%2BsA21OumwuSQUJX1ZjLsVabqR6t7tUlrThhnjEC%2FFy6AKbCy45zdftmEutKm5UcSgHspY7XBEPVAFVHLoCUXPFkr3hi2wutba44QDr5iyeqQ3%2FiAccqOLQDhAV17pG0jZfUuZS5OJaGYiWF%2B2ypOV%2F4q5UQZtDu4G2xK10aeTlC1bhUslciQpYh7PSQtau8ErcVYZ4gXYDcUXLe1lrvBU%2B0VoutFRcWQWo4qwdTlYSr8Q9caDMwc3BDgl3xZpRb%2FORnuVCJHNlla2oOYmLQ8q7Ll6Ie6pgDaQKSCl8IF3WqAgPrbgU2VxpV1kje2EdoOWGlsOJuKMd1g14OdjNp1YjNY%2B0m0s15kYgJVlaFxBVOETuAOK9eEELrDmUli%2Fo8oy94S4Xl2LzQGukEFU46RptQLy3BWWgHSBTvEp32eGRtjTjSriQBKLlShUPrSRcnK2qtIB4Zw3tQNRAbF5FB0vhoS57JFXzZmUtuLiy5gNlTTixlkgB8Y4byhAX0HJ4Y%2FcmWkjz0NrSaMNJ5EiNi3%2FSpPlIayqA3UBcIG5tQTuwBcQOJx3AsrSzxHJ4bKs9U5xoqWnK4U17%2BUzPFLQ4iQ3iRtxQC3gBK5xZJjOutcaSpeYjsUZqKFmGOLxIaflU1jI2ZzuLuLGuLe2yBlrLC1tdWg7ZmWal8KHeGtXG0gLLSdZyha%2BoKYdDl7WIGxpbI7lSicyLqFkH2rVZF%2BwUnymNXNu8WUkVLqSaB6IpIGWXF3Ft1UC6rRq3mhc7TRXgLS2lrKb5VEoz6nCSrtE2V6p4aMeQ8tJaxLU4nGU9o%2BXVTrMF%2BLBgjYqvSNkjL%2BDxhmut5tDb3CF1uwJoEdday6vMTHjVs7GA3g3QU8tXxZJc6Q23yhxWckPCtZW1nLgQ12KFF5Ed3pQ0U7yKp%2Fi6YM%2FI4dZOA3FRRdvhSmaWMxtxI3JzVlP8k9qsVFWdbVvTfENCjcytUoBW46XscE3DizLi1o6KQ4%2FDlZRsWSfBCt%2BSdHGrzGHFOtjFtUgNNJQR78Qjr%2BVwzV4I65SazPJzrQbKq6bl5kapU7bbRryXLo3c3LATYIfMEs3yc1bA44bScqumvJ21jLgrhHdSktNWkONR%2BLmULMnbpQm3pOWkZxHf0R7NKKykDr9iq3ptuexOuJQRZ5lCfE96K5Ct5iNpe118WQKxVeGCxnYDmUL8iUjb2%2BXmexIu9Di9XtgpxJ9wcehuOzwt1gJx4ynEM9K9tS5X7fLempP2dmnDczwjTlLYi%2FiCnHXSe9LWic9k3qvlRTltLU%2Bp2lE1sKUG8bm2DiNpNBpJu5vwwuEdLa%2FWy6p4JL27Dg%2B0pUBsQHxu67C1Vb2dpLlU5h3bG87aS0vNXWtJtip0bbjDhqgB8TkvH1g115qttnfDoW0oNe%2B1Rs0hlqVRc8cSmYP4XBUfUXHNlQ5tqzkpNaXmHVV4lVpq1NxjhYP43JqP2FwracOh7OZQDuXmRmu5sjMO75SWE%2FE5F4%2F09s5wI5abQ0rFoVxZNTes7e7wvy053NpwJj7n4kVCDt29teWypJHFOy0VJ6sN0CrK4dpakmv5pxQeEZ8rQ%2B9alnU2knyo2k64Ix4vh5I5sVNarqW3u8z%2F4mkeEZ8LrCxXtbfWu9t8qqQK0DKHVtEubrWm%2BZ9VPCS%2BJN1828oB4gqwalrFtUjNP3bzkPg7sdXAyhyssF4upWb5Z8c8Jv5QWmpgVRxUsGoulMw%2FPQqPiZ%2Fp8JGVOLQWKAW6%2BCcyF2qGD4gfibe2ead5lXEDpQAu0rv8r2WgtZxl1Twm%2Ftls1HxHK7HDjZV51VIgWmBlSeMKr%2BxseZYXq%2BUx8aY0MxrvVnUC4XNxgYtrJY15taMmNlAztd0lhxfW6MChC1rFY%2BLVjlwzKutVdfhE7xjKXEiX3CuHFzWG0lLycogUXnTtxuaws6DiMfFK09kZQ9K1VSvJ3oRHslIFWuGftdzQUoWzlYONinBILRdaC8TTYPO%2F3nBFnKxLG2um%2BKfXOrg6vBdLrvJSCm9SJpy0RtucrMRq1Zy1woUy0B4HbN60ex0uiEN0KLk1xZXs2paKW9FIqrJrzP%2Fs5k17tJz0GE%2FxohwulGElOUTmTRWl5oI4lKRRsTPhVpIdc6sl10IsFW9WXNpROPH0TkGAVnFpx5a63WSKN5HVXBKwc1btEffsNO8kvBObS5lZTnaUMXFYqbnUltwg75h%2FusMVATXleWW7qk1Xb8KLVfiKlsIlj9Sc1FhFtjITboSTlSp8QMCO5JU11bb1ZlQdIHL4iprmktWROclqGlaWmvsSPiRAIy3lcAhk05vsWgfbU3xFVFyRWTUvSqqa2S7zHEFmRikt7yS18kxxFj6yY67UbNu86U6qIApPEUSasZb7Ek0DqXh5LHa4lDFWc6kd4uUpgsiaKR6pKQ61uHmsZrmyk1ZxpQ1oeYoAzaG4ry1zsuXisVJxpeQdc60N2DxFgGckc1ePixdpHkjVjrnS0kpc6u5SwMtTBKxkybUJN3bUfCaulsMVTVvNP%2BmyNQVe7tjlE%2BJFb1mSLVfV9jaHHS2fiao15sqOd4pL29ArbxXvldV8TPwv6XVV6YXtGTefiiqaMRei2TFXKpzUONxKFWo%2BJt5J0ltlzQxfsCqimSpv86KmrHApBbXA2s2NuKPwMfFQvOELWgvsnEjVQMYtc2UXqjm0xI0yq%2FAx8T0JtyJz8DiekWpjxWoupRqqOamp5VJPsXJt9256wz3iW8oOt1xNaWah3NZJZK7UAg6HLo%2B5tFPgke2SreUe8R1rO9xayTpALFaa2Z3mUhyo4qQ6I67MbLlsyyfFPeI71m7ey0orw2pL256WuFILVHOI41mu1IyK3u0q28094nvCXQHLtqyF9Gq5tA7E4bAViRsrNW%2FCXeK3lDTVVoBI4ZIDVHFYpbTcyIbPiF%2FTSbPT3SUtl6qAuDl4W8UzxC%2Fz6CRciALUcijT4inil%2FV2p4pLtUDcwCol8xTxF8KlKg5VQGtb4jniz7UbWAcox%2BJJ4s%2B5OLiAVnuKJ4m%2FtuawBURbszxL%2FLF4OXgh9s7yNPHHqjisgVLLPE%2F8rXYD7UCrVsXzxN%2Bq4uAGrFj8gPhTXRzKwGprmh8Qf2rlot2AvSp%2BQvyl1nikAlprh58Qf0lqolGBarX8iPhLZWBVqnVsfkb8pTaHcru61PyM%2BEtrDq2UW8sPib%2FUChBvbIcfEn%2FKxWGrpeWnxJ9qVYDyVPgp8bfa2qRmmh8Tf21lq5qfE38uveE3%2FAdr385%2FSVd%2FMAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg%3D%3D") no-repeat scroll 100% 5px transparent
```

Does anyone know what does this mean ? what ? how? and why they serve image like that ?

Comment: Removed "image-processing" tag.

Comment: If anyone is wondering what image that base 64 string represents, it's the Google broken robot - https://www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It's an inlined image (png), encoded in base64. It can make a page faster: the browser doesn't have to query the server for the image data separately, saving a round trip.

(It can also make it slower if abused: these resources are not cached, so the bytes are included in each page load.)

Comment: can you explain it more ? i mean how can we transfer an png to encoded in base 64 ? how part is missing :)

Comment: is there a maximum mb ? or something ?

Comment: I believe you are right that if this is used in a style sheet inside the web page it will likely not be cached on the client. This is only because most pages are dynamically served and no-cache is sent to the client. I believe if used in a .html or in the .css file it will likely be cached, dependent on your server configuration. I know I have to force refresh (clear the client cache) when I change these files on IIS.

Comment: @Mat if one wanted to eliminate the inlined image and instead have a URL to an image file (versus all the info of the image right there), how would they go about that, specifically in java script?

Comment: @Anna The only way to get a URL to an image file would be to decode the image and then upload the resulting file somewhere with a stable URL.

Answer (score 18):

That `data:image/png;base64` URL is cool, I’ve never run into it before.  The long string of characters is the base64 encoding of the actual image, i.e. no image call to the server.  See [RFC 2397](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) for details.

Side note:  I have had trouble getting larger base64 images to render on IE8.  I believe IE8 has a 32K limit that can be problematic for larger files.  See this other StackOverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586749/how-to-get-around-ie8-32k-limit-on-datauri-on-base64-encode) for details.

Answer (score 11):

That is, you are referencing an image, but instead of providing an external url, the png image data is in the url itself, embedded in the style sheet. data:image/png;base64 tells the browser that the data is inline, is a png image and is in this case base64 encoded. The encoding is needed because png images can contain bytes that are invalid inside a HTML document (or within the HTTP protocol even).

Comment: It's not "instead of providing an URL". It's an URL with the [`data:` scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Answer (score 1):

They serve the actual image inside CSS so there will be less HTTP requests per page.