# Using simplepie to fetching feeds which include inlined images (encoded in base64)?

Tags: wordpress, base64, simplepie, inline-images

I wish to use simplepie to fetch feeds that are using inline images encoded in base64.
Whenever I try fetching such feeds, simplepie gets stuck and does not fetch anything.

Here is some documentation on this type of image embedding:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme
And also:
[what does this mean ? image/png;base64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242319/what-does-this-mean-image-pngbase64)

Is there any way to extend simplepie to be able to handle these types of content?