# PS: Invoke-WebRequest - Second call is Encoded

Tags: powershell, webrequest

When calling a URL using

```
$source = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL
```

The first request works fine, but in the same session calling a different page from the same domain I get what looks like an encoded source.

Here is a small example 
Working URL Call (First Call)

> RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>                       Content-Language: en-US
>                       X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
>                       Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>                       Connection: keep-alive,Transfer-Encoding
>                       Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
>                       Content-Type: text/html;... Forms             : {, filter->form} Headers           : {[Content-Language, en-US],
>   [X-Frame-Options, SAMEORIGIN], [Transfer-Encoding, chunked],
>   [Connection, keep-alive,Transfer-Encoding]...} Images            :
>   {@{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=aa846a08e9b3/idm-instruments-pty-ltd-hallam-3803-logo.jpg">;
>   outerText=; tagName=IMG; title=IDM 
>                       Instruments Pty Ltd - logo; class=listing-logo enhanced->logo; alt=IDM Instruments Pty Ltd - logo;

Non Working Call (Second URL Call)

> RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>                       Content-Language: en-US
>                       X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
>                       Connection: keep-alive
>                       Content-Length: 14201
>                       Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public
>                       Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
>                       Date:... Forms             : {captcha} Headers           : >{[Content-Language, en-US], [X-Frame-Options, SAMEORIGIN],
>    [Connection, keep-alive], [Content-Length, 14201]...} Images
>   : {@{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=
>
> alt="Yellow Pages"
>   src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIwAAACMCAYAAACuwEE+AAAAG
>                       >
>   XRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAFa5JREFUeNrsXQl4FMXWrYQlLLIJAgYE>BAFZZAeRIKs8FgU1GkBQCPIEcQH9hfwqAoryFEVx+9gVAYOCCgq4REXBCIYlbD4gQESW4BKRhE2IIel
>                       >
>   3T0/N2Pv0TCaTnpk633cI011d3VV1+9atW7eqo1hkIYZYk/MKYjViJeJl/G8UsaLmmvNEiXiWeI7/zS>H+QczmzIuUCowK47LVIHYhdiReR2xNbFBM9zpC3E38kbiNuJl4kgk4GpWJ8cSFxAyuFUqSGfxZ4vmzC
>                       >
>   TgAscSHiRuJ+Q4QEjPm82d8mD+zQBBRgZhIXE8sdLCQmLGQP3siL4tAMaEFcQ4xNwSFxIy5vEwtRPMG>Dr2Jn4aRkJjxU15WAT/Rh5gWAYKiZRovu4BNdCZuiEBB0XIDrwsBE9QhJgtB0TGZ140AR2niRIVHVVD

Any Help would be great.

Comment: `src="data:image/png;base64` - that's an inline picture.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler in short what I think is happening is that the connection is still alive so sends the "outerHTML = " in some encoded format,  in the first web request outterHTML is plain text readable, apposed when when you call it the second time.

Comment: `<img style="width: 70px;" alt="Yellow Pages" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBO` that is readable HTML, it has an IMG tag in it, and the picture data for the image is inline, it's a base64-encoded PNG. As far as I can tell, that's a valid result and that's what it's supposed to look like. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242319/what-does-this-mean-image-pngbase64

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler but what i am getting is 2 different results, the top example when when i do the first invoke-webrequest (new session), the bottom is the exact same call just ran again and that its out put. why is it different?

Comment: It's the exact same call? In your question you say it's "calling a different page" .. ?