# Pass image from controller to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass an image from controller to a view as:

**Controller:**

```
model.image = AspectRatio(String.Format("~" + i.ImageUrl));
return View(model);
```

**Model:**

```
public Bitmap image { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
@model OnlineStore.ViewModels.ItemVM
<div>
    @Model.image
<div>
```

Code throwing no errors but instead of displaying image, browser is displaying following line of text:

`System.Drawing.Bitmap`

Can someone please guide?

Comment: The best way for sending image from controller to view is just sending saved image URL as string and use it in src of img tag. Other approaches may have heavy process on server side.

Comment: @SajadAfaghiy - Size of images change on different web pages in some requirements where code must resize an image to a different size than the saved size before displaying. `AspectRatio` method in my code maintains image aspect ratio while doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `Bitmap` instance to razor view that didn't show any image, because *Hypertext Transfer Protocol*, if you want to show images you might use `img` tag.

**Model:**

You can try to use `byte` array property  `imageBuffer`, to carry your image data.

```
public byte[] imageBuffer { get; set; }
```

**Controller:**

use `ImageConverter` let `Bitmap` object image data to `byte[]`

```
ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();

Bitmap imageObj = AspectRatio(String.Format("~" + i.ImageUrl));

model.imageBuffer = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(imageObj, typeof(byte[]));

return View(model);
```

**View:**

`Convert.ToBase64String` function let `byte[]` to base64 string. and img tag support display image by `base64`, just set `src` attribute and declare `data:image/png;base64` in it.

because of `img` tag support  `base64 data`

```
<img src="@String.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}",Convert.ToBase64String(Model.imageBuffer))" />
```

---

**Refer Link**

[what does this mean ? image/png;base64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242319/what-does-this-mean-image-pngbase64)

Comment: I never thought that you can convert byte array to image and pass it on src attribute. Cool way!

Comment: Just take care of how many images you are sending using the base64 encoding because you may get an `outofmemory` exception on server side.

Comment: Solution is working perfectly for me. Thank you @D-Shih for your guidance.