# How to remove data:image/png;base64 in base64 before uploading to api server through axios post in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, base64

Getting the base64 Output from this

My updated Code

```
  getCroppedImg(image, crop) {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const scaleX = image.naturalWidth / image.width;
        const scaleY = image.naturalHeight / image.height;
        canvas.width = crop.width;
        canvas.height = crop.height;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = 'high';
        ctx.drawImage(
            image,
            crop.x * scaleX,
            crop.y * scaleY,
            crop.width * scaleX,
            crop.height * scaleY,
            0,
            0,
            crop.width,
            crop.height
        );
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            canvas.toBlob(blob => {
                resolve(canvas.toDataURL());
            }, 'image/jpeg');

        });


    }
```

**How to remove this data:image/png;base64, in ReactJs**
Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks

```
src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAAEsCAYAAAB5fY51AAAgAElE..."
```

Comment: why do you want to remove the mentioned metadata. Please refer to the following link how the image gets rendered by browser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242319/what-does-this-mean-image-pngbase64/15928978#:~:text=data%3Aimage%2Fpng%3Bbase64%20tells%20the%20browser%20that%20the,within%20the%20HTTP%20protocol%20even).

Comment: The reason i want to remove is because the server is throwing the error response message - "Message":"The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character and ive tried it in postman without the header information, getting the success response "picture saved"

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to remove `data:image/png;base64` section:

```
var base64 = string.split(',')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

you may not want to remove that header information from you base64, without it, future clients may not be able to properly parse and then display your base64 strings...

It's actually important "header" type information, to inform a browser/client of the image mime type, encoding etc... Check out [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) for more details.

Comment: The reason i want to remove is because the server is throwing the error response message - "Message":"The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character

Comment: ive tried it in postman without the header information, getting the success response "picture saved"

Comment: I see, in that case, you are most likely running into an encoding issue, check out the answer by  Jim Mischel here,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114044/the-input-is-not-a-valid-base-64-string-as-it-contains-a-non-base-64-character

Comment: Its not working, any example code in react would be helpful

Comment: Oh, you would need to address the encoding issues server side.