# render image using datauri in javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, data-uri

I am trying to load an image using AJAX that is sent as data uri. Everything works fine as long as image is < 32kb. Some of the images are large in size around 500 kb. I did some research on this and found that IE8 supports only images < 32kb to be loaded using datauri.

Is there any workaround to load the image which is > 32kb or am i missing something here?

Comment: I take it you are targeting IE8?

Comment: thats right. i am targetting IE8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get around IE8 32k limit on data:uri on base64 encode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586749/how-to-get-around-ie8-32k-limit-on-datauri-on-base64-encode)

Comment: "using AJAX that is sent as data uri" => can you show us some code?

Comment: Also asked with the above with no real answers.

Comment: @epascarello : the question you mentioned doesnt have any solution to the problem mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

[Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

> Internet Explorer 8: Microsoft has limited its support to certain
>   "non-navigable" content for security reasons, including concerns that
>   JavaScript embedded in a data URI may not be interpretable by script
>   filters such as those used by web-based email clients. **Data URIs must
>   be smaller than 32 KiB in Version 8**.[3] Data URIs are supported only
>   for the following elements and/or attributes:[4]
>
> - object (images only)
> - img
> - input type=image
> - link (data URI must be base64 encoded)
> - CSS declarations that accept a URL, such as background-image, background, 
>     list-style-type, list-style and similar.
>
> Internet Explorer 9: Internet Explorer 9 does not have 32KiB
>   limitation and allowed in broader elements.

Comment: i know this part and i went thru the article on wikipedia. I am looking for a solution or workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, serve it as MHTML using some commentring tricks, described [here](http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-data-uris-in-all-browsers) and [here](http://www.phpied.com/mhtml-when-you-need-data-uris-in-ie7-and-under/).

Answer (score -1):

You could load the image data into a canvas element.
For IE8 you should have a look at [How can I use the HTML5 canvas element in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332501/how-can-i-use-the-html5-canvas-element-in-ie)

Comment: takes forever to load the image. IE stops responding and asks to stop running the script. :(

Comment: Canvas element is not supported and IE. So this is not a solution

Comment: @julmot The `canvas` element is [supported in IE since version 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas). And for IEv8 I've added a link for a workaround (and anything below IE8 should not be supported from anybody). So the downvote isn't justified... :|

Comment: @julmot And for this I've added the link to [How can I use the HTML5 canvas element in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332501/how-can-i-use-the-html5-canvas-element-in-ie) - The heck with it...!

Comment: Well a link to a compatibility view is not a solution. If you just want to share a link you should use the comment box.